# How to know a numerical value fetched by JPA was null at DB

Tags: oracle, jpa, null, default-value, numerical

I'm using JPA.I have the requirement like I have to fetch some data whose variable's data type is primitive data type in java like long, int etc.Now if I fetch it by JPA then if that variable's mapped column in DB(Oracle) has number type and it has value 'null' stored in DB(Oracle) I will have that value as 0 when I'm getting it from JPA query because java has defined 0 or 0.0 as default value for numerical primitives.I'm not able to check wheather it was null or 0.Changing all to wrapper type will cost much time.Is there is a way to find out wheather it was null at DB(Oracle)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the wrapper type, not a primitive.